# How to move a stackView containing textFields up when one of the textFields is editing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

### How to implement this similar to the attached gif?

I'm New here. Looking to implement keyboard & textFields arrangements similar to the attached gif. I Don't want to move all the view and its content up. I want to move only the stackView which contains the textfields and button while keeping the top of the view visible. Please check the gif photo https://media.giphy.com/media/S9iE9NmVDY3wGQxQx1/giphy.gif. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In textfield delegate textfieldDidBeginEditing handle the top constraint of the stack view and set the height of the upper view as zero. Otherwise you can use IQkeyboardmanager it automatically handles the constraints.